# getting aggregate from multiple joins with max date

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate

3 tables

```html
<h>DesktopGroup</h>
<table style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 81px"><colgroup><col style="width: 25px"><col style="width: 55.5px"></colgroup><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>group1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>group2</td></tr></table>

<h>machines</h>
<table style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 198px"><colgroup><col style="width: 31px"><col style="width: 67px"><col style="width: 99.5px"></colgroup><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>Desktopgroupid</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>server1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>server2</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>server3</td><td>2</td></tr></table>

<h>loadindex</h>
<table style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 456px"><colgroup><col style="width: 28px"><col style="width: 61px"><col style="width: 89px"><col style="width: 277.5px"></colgroup><tr><th>id</th><th>load</th><th>machineid<br></th><th>Createdate</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>7654</td><td>1</td><td>2019-10-15 16:54:31.430</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1235</td><td>1</td><td>2019-10-15 16:44:00.430</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4443</td><td>1</td><td>2019-10-15 16:34:31.000</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>2345</td><td>1</td><td>2019-10-15 16:25:15.222</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>3456</td><td>2</td><td>2019-10-15 16:54:31.430</td></tr></table>
```

each desktopgroup has x number of servers and each server has a given load a point in time.  (roughly every 5 min)
so what I am trying to get
desktopgroup.name, avg(load) for all machines in the group for the max(date) of the load.

```
select loadvalues.avgload, dg.Name
from CitrixMonitoring.DesktopGroups as dg
join CitrixMonitoring.Machines as m on m.DesktopGroupId = dg.id
join (select LoadIndex.MachineId, avg(LoadIndex.EffectiveLoadIndex) as avgload, max(LoadIndex.[CreatedDate]) as maxdate
from CitrixMonitoring.LoadIndex group by MachineId) as [loadvalues] on m.id = loadvalues.MachineId
where dg.name like 'live - call center desktop'
group by dg.name, loadvalues.avgload
```

I get

```
3185    LIVE - Call Center Desktop
3236    LIVE - Call Center Desktop
3249    LIVE - Call Center Desktop
3263    LIVE - Call Center Desktop
3288    LIVE - Call Center Desktop
3295    LIVE - Call Center Desktop
```

expected result should be one row with avg load for desktopgroup

```
3185    LIVE - Call Center Desktop
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? That's a JavaScript library, it has nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just `GROUP BY dg.name`. When you include `loadvalues.avgload` in the `GROUP BY` clause, it means you want a separate row for each different value of `avgload`.

But since you're just selecting a single `dg.name` in the `WHERE` clause, there's no need for `GROUP BY` at the end at all. So it should just be.

```
select loadvalues.avgload, loadvalues.maxdate, dg.Name
from CitrixMonitoring.DesktopGroups as dg
join CitrixMonitoring.Machines as m on m.DesktopGroupId = dg.id
join (select LoadIndex.MachineId, avg(LoadIndex.EffectiveLoadIndex) as avgload, max(LoadIndex.[CreatedDate]) as maxdate
from CitrixMonitoring.LoadIndex group by MachineId) as [loadvalues] on m.id = loadvalues.MachineId
where dg.name like 'live - call center desktop'
```

Comment: that query still provides me the list of servers with the name of the group.
I am shooting for avg(load) for all the servers as a group with the Max(date)

Comment: You're getting the average in the subquery that you join with.